# Update sharepoint list column inside a timer job and also fetch its current value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, custom-timer-job, yes-no-field

I have a Timer job created to send reminder emails for attendees who are registered for the events. When is send an email, i need to update "IS EMAIL SEND" column of event attendees list which is a YES/NO column.

```
    try
                {
                    string siteUrl = "http://sites/demosite/";
                    string listName = "Event Attendees2";
                    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
                    {
                        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
                        {
                            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                            {
                                SPList sPList = web.Lists.TryGetList(listName);
                                SPQuery sPQuery = new SPQuery();
//fetches all event registrations occurrence for next day
                                sPQuery.Query="<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Start_x0020_Time\" /><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type=\"DateTime\"><Today OffsetDays=\"3\"/></Value></Eq></Where>";
                            SPListItemCollection items = sPList.GetItems(sPQuery);
                            if (items.Count > 0)
                            {
                                string emails = "";
                                foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                                {
                                    var pName = item["Person Name"].ToString();
                                    var eName = item["Event Name"].ToString();
                                    
                                    if (item != null &&
                                        item.Fields.ContainsField("Person Name") &&
                                        item["Person Name"] != null)
                                    {
                                        string fieldVal = item["Person Name"].ToString();
    
                                        SPFieldUserValueCollection usersV =
                                            new SPFieldUserValueCollection(item.Web, fieldVal);
    
                                        foreach (SPFieldUserValue uv in usersV)
                                        {                                       
                                            emails = uv.User.Email;
                                            pName= uv.User.Name;                                       
    
    
    //need to check column value here
                            if(IS EMAIL SEND=='NO')
    {
                                            string ccMailAddress = "";
                                            string fromAddress = "";                                      
                                            string subject = "Reminder email for "+ eName;
                                            string body = "Hi " + pName + ",<br/><br/>Good Day!<br/><br/> This is to remind you of the "+ eName + " event you have already been registered for tommorow";
                                            StringDictionary headers = new StringDictionary();
                                            headers.Add("from", fromAddress);
                                            headers.Add("to", emails);
                                            headers.Add("cc", ccMailAddress);
                                            headers.Add("subject", subject);
                                            headers.Add("fAppendHtmlTag", "True");
                                            System.Text.StringBuilder strMessage = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                                            strMessage.Append(body);
                                            SPUtility.SendEmail(web, headers, strMessage.ToString());
    
    //need to set IS EMAIL SEND=='YES'
    
                                        }}        
    
                                       
                                    }
                                }
                            }
    
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Can u help me fix the code to fetch and update IS EMAIL SENT column? Below is the event attendees list columns:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!Convert.ToBoolean(item["IsMailSent"]))
{
   //send the mail
   item["IsMailSent"] = true;
}
```

[image: Code]

if you face any error you should check the field name because if the Title is updated it will throw an error when accessing the field/column by the old name to confirm the name go to the List Settings Page and click the field and find the actual name in the URL

[image: Correct Column Name]